# Make image and text responsive

Tags: html, css, media-queries

Hi I'm trying to make an image and text that are next to each other responsive,I'm trying to position the image on the middle of the page and the text being below the image when the website is viewed from a phone.
Is media queries the only way of doing this?
Also how can I make the text justify, and not overflow over the column2

```css
div.content {
  width: 100vw;
  display: flex;
}

div.column1 {
  width: 15%;
  background-color: #F7F7F7;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 100vh;
}

div.column2 {
  width: 70%;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.banner {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 10vh;
}

.container2 {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  padding-top: 3rem;
  justify-content: center;
}

.image2 {
  width: 100%;
  height: 60%;
  margin: 0;
}

.image2 img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: contain;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.content {
  width: 50%;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding-left: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <div class="column1">
  </div>
  <div class="column2">
    <div class="container2">
      <div class="image2">
        <img class="image2" src="img/lobby.jpg" alt="" />
      </div>
      <div class="content">
        <p> Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.
          It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="column1">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: If you make some search you will find a lot of resouce about [responsive design](https://kinsta.com/blog/responsive-web-design/).

Comment: `media queries` is not the only method but the easiest. You probably can also realize that with flexbox and CSS grid (autofit).

Answer (score 0):

As tacoshy says in the comments, a media query is the easiest way to do this. You have a lot of css in there that looks unnecessary too that could probably do with a clean up. I've removed some css and replaced it with code that makes it behave okay at small screen sizes but tbh you could eliminate a lot of what you've written to get the same effect. If what I've written isn't clear or you have any questions just drop a comment below and I'll explain.

Info on media queries on [w3schools here](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp)
A good guide to flexbox on [css tricks](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)
A good intro to flexbox from Kevin Powell [here](https://youtu.be/u044iM9xsWU) and a tutorial on youtube [here](https://youtu.be/2KL-z9A56SQ)

```css
div.content {
  /*width: 100vw; removed this as it was causing content to overflow*/
  display: flex;
}

div.column1 {
  width: 15%;
  background-color: #F7F7F7;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 100vh;
}

div.column2 {
  width: 70%;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.banner {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 10vh;
}

.container2 {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  padding-top: 3rem;
  justify-content: center;
}

.image2 {
  flex-grow: 1;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  max-width: 200px;
  /*width: 100%;
  height: 60%; removed these to use max-width*/
  margin: 0;
}

.image2 img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: contain;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.content {
  /*width: 50%;*/
  flex-grow:1;
  flex-basis: 50%;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding-left: 1rem;
}

@media screen and (max-width:600px) {
  .container2 {
    flex-direction:column;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <div class="column1">
  </div>
  <div class="column2">
    <div class="container2">
      <div class="image2">
        <img class="image2" src="https://picsum.photos/id/237/200/200" alt="" />
      </div>
      <div class="content">
        <p> Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.
          It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="column1">
  </div>
</div>
```

**Edited** with regard to the comment, set the flex-basis to determine what fraction of the width the image takes up. Here I've set it to 33%. In my example above the text shouldn't overflow. It overflows on the original example because there's 2 rules for .content, the higher specificity one sets the width to 100vw which overflows the container.

If I started from scratch I'd do the following:

```css
body, p {
 /* set the margin to 0 on the body to prevent the 100vh overflowing the viewport */
  margin:0;
}

.content {
  /* instead of having a div fill the column either side that's 15% of the screen width, just use a border */
  border-inline: 15vw solid #f7f7f7;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  gap: 0.5rem;
}

.image {
  /* the image is 1/3 of the screen width */
  flex-basis: 33%;
}

.text {
  /* and the text is the other 2/3 */
  flex-basis: 66%;
}

.image > img {
  /* make the image fit the container */
  width: 100%;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .content {
    /* flip from row to column format */
    flex-direction: column;
  }
  .image {
    /* make the image div height fit the content */
    flex-basis: 0%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
    <div class="image">
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/237/200/200" alt="" />
    </div>
    <div class="text">
      <p> Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.
        It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in</p>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Ok, and to make the image grow bigger in size compared to the text I would set flex-grow 2 right?
Another question, the media query you set did stack the items vertically, however the text appears to be hidden under the side columns instead of starting a new line. To fix this I tried to use overflow:hidden; however that didn't work, any idea of how I can do it.
Thanks for your help!

Comment: I've added another example with an explainer. Hope this helps